# Try to resolve logged error SQL Server/SQL Server 2008 R2

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2008, com

I have this logged error #10016

```
        The application-specific permission settings do not grant Local Launch permission for the COM Server application with CLSID 
        {46063B1E-BE4A-4014-8755-5B377CD462FC}
         to the user NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE SID (S-1-5-20) from address LocalHost (Using LRPC). 
        This security permission can be modified using the Component Services administrative tool.

        CLSID maps to           Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Server.DtsServer
```

I'm not using SQL Server DTS as far as I know.

DtsServer does not show up in the Component Services tool.

Does any one recognize the Server/SQL Server error?

Answer (score 2):

I know this is late but I just had and solved this problem with our CRM Server.  In a nutshell we had to give Local Activation permissions to the account that the Sql Server Agent is running under.  I did that by looking at Microsoft SQL Server Integration Services 11.0 Com process and changing its security.  I had to add the account for the Sql server agent, SQLSERVERAGENT in my case, and give that account Local Activation.  The following link explains it a little more.
[Application Specific Permissions](http://rnicholson.net/application-specific-permission-settings-grant-local-activation-permission/)

Answer (score 0):

I *think* I found an easy work around/cause...

My problem was with a task to delete old backup files. I create the task from SQL Server Manager on my desktop managing SQL Server on another platform and the error resulted when the task ran. I removed the task and re-established the task from SSM running on the same server as the SQL Server instance where the files reside. The task now works properly.